# d3.csv Load Data Shows Undefined

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to load a csv file using below code.

**Method 1:**

```
d3.csv("data/aaa.csv", function(error, data) {
        console.log(data[1]);
    })
```

The console shows `undefined` instead of the data row. Nonetheless, this is the most common method you can find on all forums.

However, if I use below method 2 loading the data, it correctly shows the data row.

**Method 2:**

```
d3.csv("data/aaa.csv").then(function(data) {
      console.log(data[1]);
    });
```

I am a bit confused why this is happening.

Comment: Both posts listed as associated explain the reason.